# How do I stop my 'GET' in JQuery until I've performed some javascript logic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form in ASP.Net MVC that looks like this below. It sumbits with a get, but before I submit I want to run some pre get processing (get geo coordinates from google maps), then if the coordinates come back I will submit to my controller. If no coordinates come back then I display some error message and don't hit the controller.

Here is my form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchQuery, new { @class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchQuery, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submitSearch" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
}
```

Here is my javascript event that will get the address and submit it to google maps.
I tried adding a event.preventDefault to the beginning to stop it from calling the forms 'GET' but that didn't work.

```js
$("#submitSearch").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById('SearchQuery').value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                if (results[0].formatted_address) {
                    region = results[0].formatted_address + '<br/>';
                }
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'Location info:<br/>Country Name:' + region +
                    '<br/>LatLng:' + results[0].geometry.location + ''
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    // Calling the open method of the infoWindow 
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

            }
            else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    });
```

Should I remove the form from my page and just call it with JQuery and Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to stop the forms submission bind the event to the forms submit rather than the submit buttons click

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //your code;
    this.submit();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bxdao6Lw/1/

Comment: why is this better then the button click event?

Comment: he still wants to submit, just wants to wait "until" he runs some other functions

Comment: Then he can put the submit handler at the bottom of the function

Comment: well, what about not using the submit handler and using event.preventDefault() in the click event, when I have my logic performed then I call $("form").submit() ?? Is there any significant reason why binding to the submit should be used vs the submit button click event?

Comment: in fact I see using the form submit handler as a bad thing because now your in somewhat of an infinite loop. submit is calling submit!

Comment: this.submit() is not a function, says Chrome developer tools!

Comment: Are you binding the event to the form? `this` should be the form dom element and `this.submit()` will execute the native form submit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of submitting the form straight away have the onclick event open a modal dialogue, run the script in this event also.

If no co-ordinates come back, display a message in the modal, else display your form with submit button.

Comment: I'm doing something very similar, only without a modal. When the submit button is clicked I will grey out the button and run the search. If nothing is found I will have a error message or validation message show up just under or next to the search query textbox.